# NET MVC Fullcalendar V5 events not displaying in calendar

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am developing fullcalendar for MVC Project. I tried everything json return no problem it works but events not showing in calendar.

Use

JavaScript: FullCalendar v5

MVC 5: Entity Framework

Please check Javascript Code

```
      events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "GetEvents",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var events = [];
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            id: v.id,
                            title: v.title,
                            start: moment(v.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
                        });
                    });
                    console.log(events);
                    successCallback(events);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
```

Please check also CONTROLLER Json Code

```
      public JsonResult GetEvents()
      {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var events = db.NobEczanes.Include(x => x.Eczane).Select(asset => new
            {
                id = asset.EventID,
                title = asset.Eczane != null ? asset.Eczane.Ad : "",
                start = asset.Tarih
            }).ToList();

            return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

Please check Chrome Console Debugger Log

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjjRk.png)

UPDATE: CONSOLE LOG DETAILS! Please Check Image Links Thanks!

[First Screen for Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwrQM.png)

[Second Screen for Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xZBu.png)

[Three Screen for Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLWX4.png)

[Full Detail Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afdb5.png)

[Visual Studio Breakpoint Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW2pO.png)

[Database Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZckVs.png)

Last Update Javascript Code and Effect start value but still same problem

```
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
      debugger;
      events.push({
        id: v.id,
        title: v.title,
        start: moment(v.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
});
```

Check Last [Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6b8X.png)

Comment: "start: k" is clearly wrong. "k" is obviously  not a date.

Comment: What value is returned for `evt.tarih` in your results, before you pass it into the moment() constructor?

Comment: Can you show us `console.log(events[0]);` fully expanded please?

Comment: Console Logs detail Images added on subject I also made some changes in the code for clarity and updated the codes on the subject, check it

Comment: Solved issue solution date format : start: moment(data.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD")

Comment: Glad you solved it. Yes, fullcalendar v5 does not understand momentJS objects, and it does not understand dd/mm/yyyy or any other locale-specific formats, it only needs yyyy-mm-dd, or a JS Date object. P.S. You should add your solution as an Answer below, not just a comment. That way, your solution will show in search results, and others with a similar problem can find it, and give you upvotes for it. If you show it only in the comments, it cannot be searched or voted for. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here issue depend via Date Format

Solution!

```
start: moment(data.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

It work fine thanks.